# How to launch camera/webcam of mac in Cocoa app using C# language in Visual studio?

Tags: cocoa, webcam, snapshot, xamarin.mac

I am new to Xamarin. Currently i am working on one of cocoa app using c# in visual studio. I need to stream live video using mac webcam/camera and on button click i need to capture the snapshot.

I tried to explore few libraries and i found that AVFoundation is not compatible in cocoa app using c#, correct if I am wrong. Even I tried to implement xam.plugin.media and OpenCVSharp but didn't got any success with that.

Any suggestion/solution will be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: The `AVFoundation` framework is available via `Xamarin.Mac`. There are some differences between iOS, macOS, watchOS and tvOS, what exactly is/was your problem using it on macOS?

Comment: @SushiHangover, I didn't find any code reference for the same. There are lot's of blogs available regarding iOS and Xamarin.forms but didn't able to find specifically for macos using C#.

Comment: SO is not a tutorial/code example site, have you tried the official sample repo from Xamarin: https://github.com/xamarin/mac-samples https://github.com/xamarin/mac-ios-samples

Comment: @SushiHangover i was able to get image in CIImage object using AVFoundation, but i am not able to fetch bytes from CIImage. I tried to use UIImage, but i didn't find UIImage dll in xamarin.mac. Any idea how i can get the bytes from CIImage or CGImage?

Comment: A `CIImage` itself is not an image. There is not a separate "UIImage dll". What "format" do you want the bytes in? A array of bytes in png/jpg format, or...?